# IPod touch 5th gen equivalent simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am new to iOS development. We are using xamarin iOS for development

Our application is mainly for iPod touch 5th Generation. so which  simulator i should use ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with chrome emulator and test.